# Movable/Draggable RectangleAnnotation to Select a Range

Tags: oxyplot

I'm using `OxyPlot` to show a rectangle annotation to the user, so it can select a range. However , I want to make this `RectangleAnnotation` Movable across the `X-axis`. Besides that, the user should be able to change the range by dragging the two sides of the rectangle (`MinimumX` and `MaximumX`).

Is this even possible? Any ideas or starter points for me to do this?